# Getting "401: Requires valid clientSecret header" for Bluemix Cordova HelloPush Sample

Tags: ibm-cloud, cordova-plugins, ibm-mobile-services

I'm using this example code: https://github.com/ibm-bluemix-mobile-services/bms-samples-cordova-hellopush

When I click to register the device I get the following error:

> com.ibm.mobilefirstplatform.clientsdk.android.push.api.MFPPushException:
>   Response: Status=401, Response Text: Error 401: Requires a valid
>   clientSecret header

The function that initializes the BMSClient accepts only two arguments BMSClient.initialize(app.route, app.guid);

Where can I pass the clientSecret?

Answer (score 0):

The Push team fixed a bug with the SDK, and I just ran through the HelloPush sample, and it worked.

The Push team has updating the Cordova Push Plugin to work with **bms-core** in the backlog at this time. Right now, it still uses **ibm-mfp-core**.

I did not run into any issues while running the sample, but if you have the Client Secret issue, performing this action should disable it:

**PUT request:**

*Endpoint:*

`https://mobile.ng.bluemix.net/imfpush/v1/apps/PUSHAPPID/verifyClientSecret`

*Headers:*

`content-type: application/json, appSecret: APPSECRET`

*Body:*

`{"verifyClientSecret": false}`

---

I just created an application from scratch to confirm that this is working today.

Here are the steps that I took:

**Step 1:** Cloned the repository & added `ibm-mfp-push` Cordova plugin

**Step 2:** [Created MobileFirst Starter Boilerplate](https://console.ng.bluemix.net/catalog/starters/mobilefirst-services-starter)

**Step 3:** Got the App Guid from my Push Notifications service instance and the App Route from the URL of my Starter Boilerplate and put it in my `index.js`.
[image: putting in creds]

**Step 4:** Configured my Push Notifications to use FCM by following directions [here](https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/services/mobilepush/t_push_provider_android.html).

**Step 5:** I then got this when I did a `cordova run`:

[image]

so I opened up Postman and did the **PUT** request above.

**Step 6:** After clicking register again, I started receiving Push Notifications:

[image: whoop whoop]

Comment: Now I get this error:
404 Not Found: Requested route ('www.ng.bluemix.net') does not exist

Comment: Using the PUT request the device now is registered but don't receive notifications.

Comment: The sample is configured for the MobileFirst Services Starter. You can deploy it here (https://console.ng.bluemix.net/catalog/starters/mobilefirst-services-starter). Use the App Name of your starter e.g. "mystartername.mybluemix.net".

Comment: Now the device is registered, but the notifications are not sent.

Comment: Hmm...could you try again? I just did it from scratch and got it working (and updated the answer above). Let me know how that works for you.